# Get checksum of chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to be able to get the checksum of a chrome extension and match that against the source code in a reliable way? the optimal way would be if a checksum is exposed through chrome apis without having to read the files.

I have searched hard for this and it seems that there is no reliable way, but i wanted to see if others have different ideas. Here are things that i considered:

- I have got an extension with both the source code, and the extension files in chrome, i have found that after comparing both directories that manifest.json got its styling changed: indention and order of properties, and one icon was modified - probably compressed. means even after reading files content this is not reliable.
- The chrome folder has a metadata folder which has hashes used to ensure the files are not modified on disks, however using these hashes is also not reliable, since these hashes are probably after the modifications mentioned above, and also there is no mention in the documentation about how these hashes are calculated, and so they can change without a prior notice.

Comment: The metadata hashes are reliable as they are generated only once when the extension is installed from the web store. You can inspect the algorithm in chromium source. Anyway, there's no API or special methods.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks ... i might have not explained this right, but i'm interested in automating the checking process ... the hashes are based on the content and i understand that, but these are internal to google chrome, they might change the implementation anytime without prior notice to anyone